# Why the Pool class in multiprocessing lack the __exit__() method in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

It is not clear to me why the [Python 2.7 implementation](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-2.7.12/pool_8py_source.html) of `Pool` does not have the `__exit__()` method that is present in the [Python 3 version](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.2/pool_8py_source.html) of the same class. Is it safe to add the `__exit__()` method (together with `__enter__()`, of course) (I just want to use `with Pool(n) as p:` ) or is there a special reason to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem like there's any reason to avoid it. Looking at it and testing it real quick didn't bring up any odd behavior. This was implemented in [*Issue 15064*](http://bugs.python.org/issue15064), it just seems it wasn't added in `2.7` (probably because only bug-fixes were considered).

Returning `self` from `__enter__` and calling `terminate` from `__exit__` as implemented in Python 3.3 should be the way to go. Instead of altering the source though (*if* that was your intention), just create a custom subclass:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool as PoolCls

class CMPool(PoolCls):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self.terminate()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind to do. Thanks for the link to the issue. Pity that they did not add the __exit__ method to Py2.7.